# Why does the following program give different output in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

Following program prints `1 2 3 4 5` at once. That means there is no time delay in printing the output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
  {
    cout << i << " ";
    // Function to sleep the thread
    this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But this program prints

1

2

3

4

5

one by one that means I’m getting the output with 0.5 sec time delay.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
  {
    cout << i << "\n";
    // Function to sleep thread
    // for 0.5 sec
    this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What is literally happening in both of above programs?

Note:**You can't see the difference of both the outputs in online compiler because they show the result after termination of program.**

Comment: "Following program prints `1 2 3 4 5` at once", seems unlikely, have you posted the correct code?

Comment: @SchwiftySzechuan It can if the output is buffered. AFAIK `std::endl` forces a flush, so if OP replaces `\n` with `<< std::endl` it shouldnt all come out at once.

Comment: OP both samples are identical...

Comment: @Borgleader The question was edited.

Comment: Question has been edited. Sorry for inconvenience. Please check out again.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate 1](https://ideone.com/MMFneY), and [Cannot duplicate 2](https://www.ideone.com/oBJaOj)

Comment: Could not repro in VS2015, numbers appeared in half second intervals with both code samples.

Answer (score 2):

The output may be line buffered, in which case only complete lines are sent to the underlying output device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the desired output, one element at a time appears with 0.5 sec of delay. Used visual studio 2015.

I suggest you to avoid online compilers.

They generally give the complete output once in a text box.

Answer (score -1):

`"\n"`  makes the output go to next line. It is newline character.

Comment: It's not the subject of the question.

Comment: yes.. question was edited that created the confusion